# ¿como actualizar valor de ng-repeat con un input dentro de el?

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items"  >
                    <td><a>{{item.nombre}}</a></td>
                    <td><a>{{item.existencia}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{item.embalaje}}</td>
                    <td><input ng:model="item.cantidad" ng:value="0" required size="4" ng:required ng:validate="integer"></td> 
                    <td><a>{{item.valorunidad}}</a></td>
                    <td><a>19%</a></td>
                    <td>{{item.valorunidad * 0.19| currency}}</td>       
                    <td>{{ (item.valorunidad) * item.cantidad | currency}}</td>

                    <td><a href ng:click="removeItem(item)"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >X</a></td>
                </tr>
```

como puedo hacer que , a medida que digite la cantidad en ng:model="item.cantidad" se actualizen los valores de la lista y me modifique la ultima operacion :  {{ (item.valorunidad) * item.cantidad | currency}}

Comment: Te lanza algun error? [A mi me funciona perfectamente](http://jsbin.com/bamekuqado/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Einer no, funciona bien la primera vez, pero el resto de las veces se mantiene igual y deja de funcionar.

Comment: Disculpa pero no comprendo lo que quieres decir con que el resto no funciona. Pudieras ser mas especifico?

Comment: @Einer la idea es que cuando digite el numero en el input el resultado : `{{ (item.valorunidad) * item.cantidad | currency}}` , cambie, la primera vez en que escribes ese trozo de codigo muestra bien, pero las siguientes veces no funciona

Comment: Agregue 4 elementos al array y en todos escribi y siempre funciona. Sobre ambiente estas trabajando? Algun detalle se te esta pasando probablemente.

Comment: @Einer estoy en angularjs, angular 1.0 sin ninguna libreria agregada solo el angular normal